# Getting product features into description as smarty - Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, html, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I have a question about Prestashop 1.7.3.0 smarty.

I would like to display a product features in product description but I dont know which smarty should I use in new prestashop. In version 1.6 it was this code:

```
 {foreach from=$features item=feature}
     {if $feature.id_feature = 1}
        <tr>
           <td>{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</td>
           <td>{$feature.id|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</td>
        </tr>
     {/if}
 {/foreach}
```

Does anyone know right solution for Prestashop 1.7?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

In this version, all products features are transferred by array $product.features. So you can use it as in the previous version but replace your `from=$features` with `from=$product.features`, and also you don't need to use `|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I see that Alexander made a small mistake, I checked and in prestashop 1.7.3.0 to display product features you should use code similar to below:

```
{foreach from=$product.grouped_features item=feature}
    <dt class="name">{$feature.name}</dt>
    <dd class="value">{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br nofilter}</dd>
{/foreach}
```

As you can see you must use `$product.grouped_features` not just `$product.features`. And you still should use `|escape:'htmlall'` - it's very important.